# WebJobsBuildereExtensions.cs Not Found error

Tags: azure-functions

I'm building an Azure Functions App (targeting .NET 6) and trying to use my own NuGet packages for my class libraries.

The strange thing is that if I try to use my NuGet packages, I get the following error. If I, however, just create a reference to the actual projects for my class libraries on my computer, everything works fine.

The main error displayed in Visual Studio is:

> WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs not found

The details display the following:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could
> not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.

I manually installed the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` NuGet package (version 7) to solve the issue but it's still throwing this error.

Any idea what maybe causing this issue?

Comment: SDK of Azure Functions are loaded with some dependencies in memory. So, the newer versions of the same libraries cannot be used by your libraries

Comment: Please Check the `.csproj` file contains the value is `v4` for  `AzureFunctionsVersion` if you've upgraded from .NET 3 to 6.

Comment: I believe no need to downgrade the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.*` as referenced [here](https://i.imgur.com/IoOHBve.png) but could you try once by downgrading the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` version to check if there is any issue in the newer version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling version 7 of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions and install version 6.0.0. Version 7 here is ".net 7" assemblies and your project targets v6. I think I had the same issue this week when Visual Studio 17.4 was released this week and auto installed .net 7.

Then when adding a reference the default is for 7.0.0 assemblies and gives FilesNotFoundException if you add that version and try to run it in your v6 project.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
Azure Functions .NET SDK will be loaded with few dependencies in the memory where it will not allow the newer versions of the same libraires.

There are some breaking changes in the code with Version 7 of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` target .NET Version 7 Assemblies and make sure the `.csproj` file contains the value is `v4` for `AzureFunctionsVersion` if the .NET Version is 6.

I believe no need to downgrade the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.*` as referenced in [NuGet Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsv6m.png) but could you try once by downgrading the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` version to check if there is any issue in the newer version of it.

Also, try updating the Azure Functions SDK Tool manually if any available by navigating to Tools > Options > Azure Functions > Check for updates:

[image]